# How to display some data differnetly than it is stored

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I seem to have a problem that I can't find a solution for. I have a table that has this format.

projectId | departmentId | plan | ETC | month | year | ID

But, I need to find a way to take that data and display it like this:

Is this something a gridview can handle, or a repeater, or something else?

Thank you.

Ben

http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/8253/image004y.png

EDIT: after reading the first solution, I think I may have not been detailed enough. In the image, the project is a list of all projects. I have successfully listed this in a repeater control. In the table layout I show above I store "buckets". The bucket is a department linked to a month and year. So, for example, a project could be two months and enlist four departments. In that case, there would be 8 records. Each department would have two records, one for each month. In this table is also a plan field and an ETC field. The plan field is how many hours the estimate people estimate for each month, and the ETC is how many hours the department estimates. Basically, I have the project grouping, but **I can't figure out how to list the departments vertically and the month/year horizontally, then make them able to be saved when the user enters the plan numbers**. I think the part in bold sums up the exact part I am having trouble with.

I hope that clears up what I am trying to do. Sorry, if my question was misleading.

- when I edited this it wouldn't let me show the picture, but the link is here.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a control/break report.  It can be tricky to do in asp.net, but it's not impossible.

The code is in C#, but my answer here might help you:
[asp:repeater - headers at section change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507215/asprepeater-headers-at-section-change)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry, I think I didn't detail my need well enough so I edited my original post.